# Win 10 64 bit goes to sleep 10 min after waking using Task Scheduler Rule

Tags: sleep

In a related thread ([Task Scheduler won't wake the computer](https://superuser.com/questions/51967/task-scheduler-wont-wake-the-computer/1487501#1487501)) moderatemisbehaviou successfully described how to put a PC to sleep and wake it using task scheduler. This was problematic in Windows 10. His solution finally solved my initial problem of getting my PC to wake up at a specified time. However, I now have a new issue where the PC goes back to sleep 10 minutes after task scheduler wakes it. If I wake the PC manually, or simply turn on the PC, it only goes to sleep when task scheduler tells it to. However, if it wakes from task scheduler based on the new rule created using PSshutdown.exe, it puts itself back to sleep 10 minutes later. I have 'never sleep' set in all of my power plans. The only thing different when the PC comes back on is that it is not logged in. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Elevated as administrator run `powercfg /hibernate off`, reboot, and then after the actual "restart" not "shutdown" run your test again. It is important to press the "restart" option after changing the "hibernate" and/or any other power saving modes, etc. and then test after that.

Comment: Thanks Pimp Juice IT ... I will give that a try if my current test doesn't work, but I may have found a solution. In typing out the question it occurred to me that it may 'sleep' because it isn't logging in.  So I turned off the requirement to log in after sleep and I think that may have done it.  I don't need to lock it as it is a home PC.

Comment: Now requiring login after sleep fixed it.